purchase coins on phantom wallet and its not showing even the swap was successful, the swap was from sudc to gobi
I swap usec to gobi on the phantom wallet, and a lot of times fails, but I continue trying until it is successful, but I can't find the coin on my wallet; then I try again, and the same thing happens, I already tried to see if it was hidden and it's not.
